# Check duplicate entry to the inserted table while using a subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, mariadb

I have two tables: Employee and Test. I need to insert data from Employee to Test table. I am doing this successfully.

But, the problem is that, I need to check duplicate entry in the ***Test Table***. That means if there exists a row with the same EmployeeId and UserId, it should not be inserted the Test table from the employee. I am using MaridaDB. I used **IGNORE**  keyword in my query, but unfortunately this is not checking the duplicate! I am stuck in this :(

#### Employee

| Id | UserId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |

#### Test

| Id | EmployeeId | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

**The query I am using:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO authdb.test (EmployeeId, UserId)

(SELECT e.Id, e.UserId FROM basedb.employee e
WHERE e.UserId != 0);
```

Comment: Also note, the `SELECT` statement doesn't need to be in parentheses and technically isn't a sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't INSERT and SELECT to the same table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
(EmployeeId INT NOT NULL,
UserId INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( EmployeeId, UserId))
AS SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.UserId
FROM EmployeeId e
LEFT JOIN Test
  USING (EmployeeId, UserID)
WHERE Test.EmployeeId IS NULL
   AND e.UserId != 0
```

Followed by:

```
INSERT INTO Test (EmployeeId, UserId)
SELECT * FROM tmp
```

This is subject to race conditions if `Test` items are removed between statements.

Answer (score 1):

[INSERT IGNORE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/#insert-ignore) relies on a primary or unique key for determining the what is unique.

So either:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE KEY eu_uniq (EmployeeId,UserId);
```

or:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId,UserId);
```

This assumes `Id` isn't a primary key already. If there's no use of it, it can be removed.

Comment: I understand what you say. But, I have no way to define this as primary or unique key. So, is there any other way what you suggest?

Comment: @AbhijitMondalAbhi If you can't define a key on the table, how would you decide which row is duplicate and which one is not?

Comment: @danblack Test table might have duplicate data. That's not my problem. I will just insert data from Employee to Test. But, if there is already the same EmployeeId and UserId in the Test table I have to ignore inserting in this case, otherwise I will insert.